# Hibernate Session

Tags: hibernate, jpa, seam

I am using Seam + EJB + JPA + Hibernate and JbossAS6 as my application server.
I have to convert JPA code to hibernate, On deployment i get the following error.

2011-07-06 01:49:15,122 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (HDScanner) Error installing to PostClassLoader: name=vfs:///opt/jboss6/server/default/deploy/SMS-ear.ear state=ClassLoader mode=Manual requiredState=PostClassLoader: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Exception while loading interceptor classes for unit vfs:///opt/jboss6/server/default/deploy/SMS-ear.ear/SMS-ejb.jar/

Heres what i changed in the original working code :
Orignal code :

```
   Query userQuery = em.createSQLQuery("select u.username from User u where u.username=#{user.username}");
   List existing = userQuery.getResultList();
    List existing = userQuery.getResultList();
```

Modified Code:

```
     org.jboss.ejb3.entity.HibernateSession hs = (HibernateSession)entityManager;
     org.hibernate.Session em = hs.getHibernateSession();
    log.info("Hibernate session"+em);

     List existing = em.createSQLQuery("select u.username from User u where u.username=#{user.username}").list();
```

I want to get hibernate Session in my application
I am quite new to JPA. I am stuck with this problem.
Is this the right way to get a session?

Regards
Jamshed

Answer (score 2):

It seems seam is allowing this query syntax (which is odd). Your exception seems unrelated to the change.

- revert the change and make sure it starts working again
- clean the environment
- restart

---

Original answer:

`WHERE u.username=:username`

and then `query.setParameter("username", user.getUsername())`

Comment: +1 for @Bozho; and i recommend to use `em.createQuery(..)` since it seems that you are using your object model.

Comment: @jamshed-katta is using seam managed persistence here, and that syntax is correct. There's little chances that the query is executed at deployment time so the reported deployment error doesn't seem related to this kind of changes in the code.

Comment: so seam interferes with the query-language? That sounds odd.. Updated the answer